# How to find out why Chrome displays an image as "favicon"?

Tags: google-chrome, favicon

I am currently working on a new website which I already uploaded to a webserver. Interestingly, Google chrome shows an icon as a "favicon" that has no relationship to the page. There is no favicon mentioned in the CSS, the (static) HTML code, and there is also no "favicon.ico" in the directory that Apache2 serves.

Is there any way to find out *why* Google Chrome uses the icon? There are other subdomains on the web server that use the same CSS style (and HTML template) for which Google Chrome does not use the icon.

Comment: What does Chrome display? Is it an icon you know? Or is it completely out of nowhere?

Comment: @philippe_b It's the favicon of https://www.liveconfig.com/en/ - but "liveconfig" is not running on the server. I only found is using a reverse image search.

Comment: When it cannot find a favicon, Chrome often reuses a previous icon that might fit. For example, if there was an icon on http://localhost (an old project you have worked on a month ago) and now you access http://localhost again (a brand new project), Chrome can well pick the old icon if there is none at the moment.